# Why does object index not reset when deleting properties?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to remove a few objects from an array:

```
    obj = {
    "0":{
        test: "test",
        test: "test"
    },
    "1": {
        test1: "test1",
        test1: "test1"
    },
    "2": {
        test2: "test2",
        test2: "test2"
    }
}
```

If I remove an item like

```
delete obj[1];
```

I do get the following:

```
    obj = {
    "0":{
        test: "test",
        test: "test"
    },
    "2": {
        test2: "test2",
        test2: "test2"
    }
}
```

But I would like to have to have the obj with indexes 0 and 1. Because strange enough if I ask the .length of the result (after removing the item) it gives me 3 and I need the correct length in the rest of the application.

I realize this is a repeat question (practically forged), but the question I'm looking for was never answered. I would like to it behaves this way? Is there a way to reset the index?

Comment: That isn't an Array. It is an Object with String keys.

Comment: Even if it were an array you'd end up with `[object, <1 empty slot>, object]` - for an array, you'll want to use `.splice` to remove an item and shift the others up

Comment: P.S. - this has nothing to do with JSON - you are manipulating a plain ol' javascript **object** (JSON is only ever a string)

Comment: *"from a JSON array"* - That isn't JSON *or* an array. Why don't you use an actual array and remove items with `.splice()` so that element indices will automatically be renumbered as needed?

Comment: Sorry, Javascript object. That's for correcting me. Also, I learned that splice() was the way to go, but I don't know why? Why does splice reset the index and delete doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `obj` looks like `Array` but is not an `Array`.

What you have todo:

- Convert `obj` to `Array` by add `length` property and use Array.from(obj) of **ES6**
- use `Array.splice` to remove items of the Array.
- convert the `Array` back to `json object` by `Array.forEach`

see this code snippet.

```js
var obj = {
  "0": {
    test: "test",
    test: "test"
  },
  "1": {
    test1: "test1",
    test1: "test1"
  },
  "2": {
    test2: "test2",
    test2: "test2"
  },
  "length": 3
};

// method of ES5
//var arr1 = [].slice.call(obj);

// method of ES6
var arr1 = Array.from(obj);

console.log(arr1);

//delete arr1[1];
arr1.splice(1, 1);
console.log(arr1);

console.log(arr1.length);

// convert back to json
obj = {};
arr1.forEach(function(item, index) {
  obj[index] = item;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an object indexed with strings:

```
{
    "0":{
        test: "test",
        test: "test"
    },
    "1": {
        test1: "test1",
        test1: "test1"
    },
    "2": {
        test2: "test2",
        test2: "test2"
    }
}
```

To make an array, do:

```
[
    {
        test: "test",
        test: "test"
    },
    {
        test1: "test1",
        test1: "test1"
    },
    {
        test2: "test2",
        test2: "test2"
    }
]
```

Also, the above are a Javascript object and a Javascript array. Proper JSON  would have string, non-duplicate keys:

```
[
    {
        "test": "test"
    },
    {
        "test1": "test1"
    },
    {
        "test2": "test2"
    }
]
```

Comment: *"A proper JSON array would have string, **non-duplicate** keys:"* - It's OK for separate objects to have the same key names, so an array can hold three different objects that all have a `"test"` property. Simply adding quotation marks doesn't create JSON - JSON is a *string* syntax, so `var obj = {"test":"test"}` still isn't using JSON.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for pointing it out. I mistyped `object` with `array`. It's fixed now :)